# NeuralNetwork toolbox octave ❬ symbol

Tags: networking, octave

I am using the Neural network tool box in octave, however in the user guide example 1, line 00035, what is that square symbol representing?

link to the example book:
http://www.plexso.com/61_octave/neuralNetworkPackageForOctaveUsersGu.pdf
example starts on page 8, continues onto 9 and I get confused on line 35, I understand they want to delete those columns but why use that symbol?

They use the symbol again on line 54/55, WHY?! How do I program that symbol, what if I have no columns to delete for my data?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no weird symbol, only square brackets. Your pdf viewer must be using some weird fonts. The code of the actual examples are:

```
## online 35
mInput(:,[4 8 12]) = []; # delete column 4, 8 and 12

## on lines 54 and 55
mInput(:,1:nValiSets) = [];
mOutput(:,1:nValiSets) = [];
```

That's just an open square brackets `[` followed by a closing square brackets `]` which translates to " replace the values of this indexes with nothing".